# How do I get domain from HTTP_REFERER in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-referer

I'm trying to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to all but cannot use wildcard since it's not allowed with allow credentials.
So my solution is to set origin header to whatever the domain is, something like:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{HTTP_REFERER}e"`

but that includes URI as well.
I can I strip uri form HTTP_REFERER so i get https://www.example.com ?

Many thanks

Comment: how does one use php in htaccess?

Comment: Why would you use the _referrer_ for this? Makes little sense. You got the info you need already - the requesting client has send it in the `Origin` header. So send the content of _that_ back, if you just want to allow access from basically anywhere, but without using the `*` wildcard.

Comment: How do I access it then?  There is no ORIGIN variable.I will use whatever makes sense.

Comment: _“How do I access it then?”_ - the same way you tried to access the `REFERER` – both are HTTP request headers, so it works the same way for both …

Comment: `Origin` is sent by browsers for anything that should supply `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response headers, it's how that system works. `Referer` has nothing to do with that and can be modified or not sent at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SetEnvIf Origin ".+" ACAO=$0
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ACAO}e"
```